# Counter offer after leaving the company

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process

I was leading a team of 90 people at my previous company. I had amazing teams, supportive managers, and a high level of freedom to do my work. Anyway, I left the company due to no-clear scope of work and the plan to move the development work to a cheaper country. Moving the labor to a cheaper country is a good business decision but it hits me as an engineering leader. I won't get to work on the fun part anymore.

Fast forward, I started at a new company. People are equally amazing, technically strong, and welcoming. I get to do a few cool technical stuff that I enjoy. The only thing I feel off is I signed up for a bigger work scope while I get a significantly smaller scope and smaller teams.

Last week, I got a call from my previous company asking if I wanted to come back. They promised to solve the scope of work issues but the development work is still going to a chapter country. They would also offer $60k more than my current package.

I know moving for money is not a good idea. However, $60k is a bit of money and it is really tempting to go for it. It is hard to choose between the work that I enjoy vs the money to support my family.

I read a few articles about "why not to accept a counteroffer" and I want to hear the thoughts & experiences on this.

Comment: *"They promised to solve the scope of work issues"* - Note that this a decidedly different claim than "They have solved the scope of work issues".

Comment: You worked for them for several years. If you believed them OR they kept their promises then you would not be posting here.

Comment: What is most important? Enjoy your work or feed your family?

Comment: @Joe he said so himself. Apparently that is his dilemma

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Apparently I understood "It is hard to choose between the work that I enjoy vs the money to support my family." differently.

Comment: At that point it's not a counter-offer. It is a completely new offer. You've **already left and started a company**.

Answer (score 5):

Rule #1: Never accept a counteroffer.
Rule #2: $60k is $60k and can override other rules.

(And to put text into two different lines: Two spaces at the end of the first line).

Comment: Voting this up, because of Rule #1. I just had a recruiter friend I was talking about this the other day. Something like 95% of people who take the counter are still gone inside of six months. (Probably just a made up stat, but he was pretty emphatic about it)

Comment: @RogerHill it is made up, I think there was a question on here about it at some point and there's zero evidence that's true.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you were not 'leading' a team of 90. I am guessing that you were either the director of a department and you were leading managers of devs or you were leading architectural design for the org. If that was truly the case and you were leading a flat team of 90 people, that sounds insane. I would run screaming from that role if it was offered me regardless of the pay.

The reason I am wondering about this, is because of what the 'fun stuff' would be. In either case, I wouldn't think the work would change much regardless of where your teams physically were located. In the event you were a director, then I would think that you would have quite a bit of control over the org to steer it as you see fit. Unsure why someone else needs to fix your work situation for you.

I am not calling BS on your story here. This scenario as you described it just sounds really odd, but whatever, it is what it is.

If you are really responsible for 90 people, then you should be making enough you can easily make ends meet and $60k more isn't really a huge pay increase. If you are responsible for that many people and you are having finical problems making ends meet, you need to either get a raise to market value or take a serious look at your expenditure on recreational drugs. Something about that seems off...

Assuming that you really don't *need* the money, go do whatever makes you happy. You will never lie on your deathbed and say: 'Boy, I wished i took on more soul crushing projects that paid really well...'

Comment: ...but you may lie on your deathbed and wish you'd taken a job that allowed you to buy your dream-home, spend your retirement travelling, send you kids to a good school, etc.  Money isn't everything at all, but it's a useful tool to do some things in life which matter.

Comment: I don't know what is common salary for a manager of 90 people, but I don't think it is in the range where additional $60k per year don't matter?

Comment: I didn't say that 60k doesn't matter. $1 per year more is a raise that could matter if you need a dollar more to get by. The question is how big of a raise is it? If the person is making $60k, then this is double the money. If they are making $300k a year, its just a 20% bump.

60k might be a huge amount or just a new matched set of jet skis for the summer house.